# How can I use comparison operators with boxed numerics of unknown types in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, linq-expressions, comparison-operators

I want to build functions that compare the values of two objects and behave identically to the built in comparison operators. I *cannot* know the types of the objects at compile-time and only have access to them as objects. Any solution that relies on casting them to their underlying types or changing the function to be a generic would not be helpful for these reasons.

My naive first implementation would be something like:

```
bool LessThan(object left, object right) {
    return left < right;
}
```

but unfortunately this results in the error

```
error CS0019: Operator `<' cannot be applied to operands of type `object' and `object'
```

I then tried using LINQ expressions

```
bool LessThan(object left, object right) {
    BinaryExpression expression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(left), Expression.Constant(right));
    return (bool) Expression.Lambda(expression).Compile().DynamicInvoke());
}
```

which works when the two objects have the same type but you get an error like

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The binary operator LessThan is not defined for the types 'System.Single' and 'System.Double'.
```

when the objects have different types.

Is it OK to convert them both to doubles and then do the comparison?

```
bool LessThan(object left, object right) {
    return ((double) Convert.ChangeType(left, typeof(double))
         < ((double) Convert.ChangeType(right, typeof(double));
}
```

This seems to give the desired behavior but I suspect that the conversions will lead to information loss in some cases.

Any ideas for better solutions?

Comment: Did you consider using IComparable?

Comment: I did try casting them to IComparable, but it doesn't include these operators. It has `CompareTo` but this runs into the same issues with supporting different types that the LINQ stuff does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the laziest solution is:

```
bool LessThan(dynamic left, dynamic right) {
    return left < right;
}
```

This will of course generate a runtime exception if the 2 types really cannot be compared.

> This seems to give the desired behavior but I suspect that the conversions will lead to information loss in some cases.

If you compare a `Double` and a `Single`, C# will convert the `Single` to a `Double` anyway. They cannot be compared otherwise.

Comment: I was thinking more about a `long` to a `double` as the place where there might be issues because of their logarithmic nature. Do you know if this is the conversion that takes place when comparing those two types?

I would prefer to do it without adding an additional assembly reference but I didn't mention that and your solution is a good one.

Comment: @Ivanna When you compare a `long` and a `double`, the `long` will be converted to a `double`. It is possible to lose information because a double has a precision of only 53 bits (not every `long` can be represented by a `double`). For instance, 4000000000000000001d and 4000000000000000000L will be considered equal. But there's nothing you can do about that anyway. C# must convert one to the other in order to compare them. But you can let `dynamic` take care of that.